# Roots of $e^{(z^{2})}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots

I’m looking for complex roots of $e^{(z^{2})}=1$ on the inside of the circle |z|=3.
I have found $0, \sqrt{\pi}\cdot \{1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i\}$. Is that it, wolfram alpha doesn’t help:/

Thank you

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I corrected my mistake

Comment: @BarryCipra I am looking for roots where it equals 1, not 0

Comment: Solve $e^w = 1$ for $|w| \le 9$; then, for each of those, solve $z^2 = w$.

Comment: @GEdgar That is the way I came up with those I mentioned (using complex log), but I am getting a wrong result in the following computation

Comment: I think your answer is right, except I would write $\pi$ and not $(pi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Let $z = x + iy$, so we have:
$$
e^{z^2}=1 \iff e^{x^2-y^2}e^{2ixy} = 1 \iff \left\{ \begin{align}x^2-y^2&=0,\\ 2xy &= 2k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb Z.\end{align}\right.
$$

Thus, considering positive and negative $k$'s, we end up with cases where $x = y$ or $x = - y$, so $z = \sqrt{k\pi}(\pm 1 \pm i),\ k\in\mathbb N$.

Finally, $|z|\leq 3 \iff \sqrt{2k\pi} \leq 3 \iff k \leq \frac 9{2\pi}\iff k = 0,1.$ These give the 5 solutions that you listed.

[Here is a Wolfram Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7B%5C%5BExponentialE%5D%5E%28z%5E2%29%3D%3D1%2CAbs%5Bz%5D%3C%3D3%7D%2Cz%5D) for the solutions.